Is xlwings in python able to pass =INDIRECT as a formula when using ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Add?
looking for some guidance.  I'm trying to add validation to a range of cells in a .xlsm file.  I want to dynamically add validation to some cells in column C, dependent on whether a value is present in column A.  My code seems to correctly create the dynamic name "EndorsementRange" as I can verify it's in the .xlsm file, but the validation itself is failing.  Here's the relevant portions of the code:
LIBRARIES
import openpyxl  # Library for reading and writing Excel files
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation # Module to add data validation rules
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows  # Function to convert a DataFrame to rows for openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook.defined_name import DefinedName  # Import for creating named ranges
import pandas as pd  # Data manipulation and analysis library
import win32com.client as win32  # Library for interacting with Excel and other Windows applications via COM
import xlsxwriter  # Library for creating Excel files with advanced formatting, charts, and images
import xlwings as xw  # Library for automating Excel with Python and enabling Python scripts within Excel
import os  # Library for interacting with the operating system, including file and directory operations
import time  # Library for adding delays

CODE THAT DEFINES THE NAMED RANGE AND ADDS IT TO THE .XLSM FILE
    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print(f"File '{file_path}' does not exist.")
        return
    
    # Load the workbook
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path, keep_vba=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading workbook: {e}")
        return

    # Define the Named Range for the endorsements sheet column
    endorsements_sheet = workbook["endorsements"]
    max_row = endorsements_sheet.max_row
    endorsement_range = DefinedName('EndorsementRange', attr_text=f"'endorsements'!$A$2:$A${max_row}")
    workbook.defined_names.add(endorsement_range)

    # Save the workbook with openpyxl
    workbook.save(file_path)  

CODE THAT IS SUPPOSED TO ADD VALIDATION
    # Use xlwings to apply data validation
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    wb = xw.Book(file_path)
    ws = wb.sheets['CSR24_Checklist']

   # Apply data validation using xlwings to ADD dynamic validation to cells C100-C140 if "Option 2: Existing Endorsement" is selected in column a on the same row.
    for row in range(100, 140):
        cell = f'C{row}'
        try:
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Delete()  # Clear any existing validation
            validation_formula = f'IF(A{row}="Option 2: Existing Endorsement", "EndorsementRange", "")'
            print(f"Applying validation to cell {cell} with formula: {validation_formula}")  # Debugging statement
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Add(
                Type=3,  # Type 3 is for list validation
                AlertStyle=1,
                Operator=1,
                Formula1=f'=INDIRECT({validation_formula})'
            )
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InCellDropdown = True
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ShowInput = True
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ShowError = True
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InputTitle = 'Select Endorsement'
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InputMessage = 'Select an endorsement from the list if "Option 2: Existing Endorsement" is selected in column A.'
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ErrorTitle = 'Invalid Entry'
            ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ErrorMessage = 'Invalid entry'
            print(f"Data validation applied to cell {cell} with formula =INDIRECT({validation_formula})")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error applying data validation to cell {cell}: {e}")

        
    # Save and close the workbook with xlwings
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
    app.quit()

THE VALIDATION FAILS FOR EACH CELL, TERMINAL PRINTS THIS OUT FOR EACH CELL
Applying validation to cell C100 with formula: IF(A100="Option 2: Existing Endorsement", "EndorsementRange", "")
Error applying data validation to cell C100: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

HOWEVER, THAT TYPE OF LOGIC WORKS FINE IF I DON'T USE INDIRECT() AS IN THIS CODE:
    for row in range(start_row, end_row):
        cell = f'A{row}'
        ws.range(cell).value = ''  # Add default value
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Delete()  # Clear any existing validation
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Add(
            Type=3,  # Type 3 is for list validation
            AlertStyle=1,
            Operator=1,
            Formula1="=validation_lists!$A$1:$A$2"
        )
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InCellDropdown = True
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ShowInput = True
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ShowError = True
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InputTitle = 'Endorsement Swap Options'
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.InputMessage = 'Use "Option 1: New Endorsement" if the renewal attachment has not been uploaded to CSR24 yet.\n\nUse "Option 2: Existing Endorsement" if the attachment was previously uploaded to CSR24'
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ErrorTitle = 'Invalid Entry'
        ws.range(cell).api.Validation.ErrorMessage = 'Invalid entry'

I've tried hard coding the formula, i've tried using a helper function, both with the same results.  When I used the help column that has this formula <IF(A{row}="Option 2: Existing Endorsement", "EndorsementRange", ""> I could see the logic working based on the value in column A, and if I manually type the =INDIRECT formula into excel itself it works fine, and recognizes the defined name range.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I believe there is nothing is wrong with your validation formula, I tried to add it using XlsxWriter and it works fine. Not sure about openpyxl or xlwings. I am on a Mac, and I never managed to add data validation successfully using those two packages.

The assumption is that at the time the formula is added to DV, it returns an Excel error. Maybe you can try setting your visibility to True, and add a Bookmark at ws.range(cell).api.Validation.Add(... and run the code in Debug mode. When the code stops at the Bookmark go to the Excel Sheet and add the DV manually with the details the code has created, validation_formula in INDIRECT and see if Excel accepts it without error.

Thank you both!  It looks like the formula works, but it was first giving a warning that it currently evaluated to an error.  I was able to create a default range so that the IF function returned an alternate range instead of None and that seemed to do the trick
